# Why is an inherited function ignoring an overridden function that was called in the original function?

Tags: c++, overriding

It was working fine before and the function wasn't being ignored. I made some changes to an HLSL shader, and added two overloaded functions(`Render` and `UpdateBuffers`) with an additional XMFLOAT4 parameter between when it worked and when it stopped working, which I don't think should have affected it.

I have a class called `TexturedRect`, and a derived class `TexturedSpritesheet`. A function called `Render` calls `UpdateBuffers`, which is overridden in `TexturedSpritesheet`. 
When I call `TexturedSpritesheet::Render`, it ignores the override and uses `TexturedRect::UpdateBuffers`.

**TexturedRect.h (including only lines relevant to the question):**

```
public:
    bool Render(ID3D11DeviceContext*, int, int);
    bool Render(ID3D11DeviceContext*, int, int, DirectX::XMFLOAT4);
protected:
    bool UpdateBuffers(ID3D11DeviceContext*, int, int);
    bool UpdateBuffers(ID3D11DeviceContext*, int, int, DirectX::XMFLOAT4);
```

**TexturedRect.cpp (including only lines relevant to the question):**

```
bool TexturedRect::Render(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, int positionX, int positionY) {
    bool result;
    m_posX = positionX;
    m_posY = positionY;
    result = UpdateBuffers(deviceContext, positionX, positionY);
    if (!result) return false;

    RenderBuffers(deviceContext, false);

    return true;
}

bool TexturedRect::Render(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, int positionX, int positionY, DirectX::XMFLOAT4 color) {
    bool result;
    m_posX = positionX;
    m_posY = positionY;
    result = UpdateBuffers(deviceContext, positionX, positionY, color);
    if (!result) return false;

    RenderBuffers(deviceContext, true);

    return true;
}
```

**TexturedSpritesheet.h (including only lines relevant to the question):**

```
protected:
    bool UpdateBuffers(ID3D11DeviceContext*, int, int);
    bool UpdateBuffers(ID3D11DeviceContext*, int, int, DirectX::XMFLOAT4);
```

Comment: TL;DR virtual functions?

Comment: The problem with "including only lines relevant to the question" is because this is not something you can actually claim to be an authority on. After all, if you were then you would, by definition, know what the problem is and you wouldn't need to ask anything. This is why for question of this kind you must provide a [mcve], as explained in stackoverflow.com's [help]; otherwise it is unlikely that anyone can figure out an answer, since there's only a very small chance that what you think is relevant, actually is.

Answer (score 0):

In order for a member function to be redefined in a derived class, it must be marked as virtual. This will allow the program to resolve the actual function to call at runtime by refering to the vtable (a table of function pointers maintained by the class.)

Your header file for **TextureRect.h** should then read:

```
virtual bool UpdateBuffers(ID3D11DeviceContext*, int, int);
virtual bool UpdateBuffers(ID3D11DeviceContext*, int, int, DirectX::XMFLOAT4);
```

Do also note that whenever inheriting from a class, it is good practice to declare the base destructor as virtual as well. This will save you headaches in the future, if ever you need to free any memory in the destructor.